# Get access to the array from the event handler

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, global

I am quite new at JavaScript and I think that I understood the concept of global and local variables well.

The problem is this: I define an array `maxVal` outside of the event handler.  The event handler is a "`onclick`" event handler. It runs when i click on elements. After that i want to get access to the new updated value of `maxVal` to use that value in a new function called `UseValue`.
How to solve the problem?

```
    var maxVal = []

    .on("click", function(d) {

    maxVal = Math.max.apply(null, newArray);
    }

   function UseValue {
//use the updated value of maxVal 
}
```

Comment: Call the function.

Comment: Since `console.log()` is outside the event handler, it runs immediately, not after the event happens.

Comment: @Barmar: how can i run console.log AFTER i used the event handler?

Comment: The point is that `console.log` is not happening  *after* the event occured.

Comment: does the console show an error?

Comment: Create another function which contains your `console.log()` then call that function from the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `console.log(maxVal);` statement inside the event handler. Otherwise, it runs when the page loads, not after the event occurs.

```
function eventhandler () {
    do something with maxVal;
    console.log(maxVal);
}
```

You could also use the variable in other event handlers, as long as those events happen after the above event handler runs.

Comment: Thanks for this. The reason why i placed the console.log outside of the event handler is, that I wanna use that value after i used the event handler. It is just a simple click event.

Comment: Then you have to use it in the handler for some other event that occurs after you click. Like you click on something to set the variable, then submit a form, and use the variable in the form's submit handler.

Comment: When a function is an event handler, it runs in the future (when the event occurs). You can't use the result before it executes. So anything that depends on the result has to run after the event occurs.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. What do you mean with "click on something to set the variable, then submit a form, and use the variable in the form's submit handler."? Submit a from means to write a function to call inside the event handler?

Comment: I was just using that as an example of something that might use the variable after you click something. It could also be that you click something else.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question to explain what you really want to do with this variable.

Comment: For instance, maybe you have a button that calculates the max, and then another button to display the result. The event handler for the second button would display the variable.

Comment: The last edit is not helpful. Explain what your application is doing. Why does it need to access the variable from outside, what is that other code that needs to access doing?

Answer (score 0):

can you show us your code ?
because with the code you post here, you define a variable which store an empty array, you define a function, and display your variable inside your console. But you never call your function !

```
var maxVal = [];
function test() {
    maxVal.push(1);
    showValue();
};
test();
function showValue() {
    console.log(maxVal)
}
```

This should display 1

Comment: I think "do something with maxVal" is intended to mean that he updates it in some way.

Comment: The function is in an event handler, it runs when he clicks on something.

Comment: yeah he named it as an event handler. but with the code he shows, there is not addEventListener, no call to the function or other stuff, so really hard to find the problem

Comment: He's edited the question and added "It runs when i click on elements."

Comment: The fact that it runs as an event handler is all the information you need to answer the question. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. The reason why i use console.log outside of the event handler is, that i wanna use that value. but if console.log does not show up a value, then i guess, i cannot use it?

Comment: Didn't saw the update when I posted 
so I updated my answer, this way, when you will trigger your eventHandler it will call your function to display the value.
Without that, your console.log() will be called when you will load your page

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function name doesn't have braces, it should be function `eventhandler(){}`
2. You have to call the function as `eventhandler();` before the code in the function gets executed

Comment: Based on the name, I think he's using it as an event listener, not calling it directly.